# Apache mod_rewrite | RewriteCond doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I own a WordPress site, and I have DDoS Attack on /wp-login.php. What I am trying to do, is to restrict the access to this file with mod_rewrite, but with no luck.

More specific, what I am trying to do, is to allow access for this file, only to users using the keywork google in the query string. If the keyword does not exists, then I like to redirect the user to google web site.

Example:

- Allow : http://www.my-site.ext/wp-login.php?google
- Redirect : http://www.my-site.ext/wp-login.php to http://www.google.com

The htaccess I am using is the following, but it seem that not works:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILE} \/wp\-login\.php
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !google
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.google.com/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I rewrite this rule, in order to allow the above functionality to work ?

**Note:** I have try the above rules without the first RewriteCond that check for the requested file name, and the redirection to google is prerformed normaly, but what I like to do is to limit the redirection only for the wp-login.php

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your code with with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^google [NC]
    RewriteRule ^wp-login\.php$ http://www.google.com/ [R=301,L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

Make sure to test in a different browser or clear your browser cache.